# How to create trapezoid shadow under image?

Tags: html, css, shapes, shadow

Is there a way to create a trapezoid shadow effect underneath a image such as the one in the image?

[image]

I only know create trapezoid with border. What i've came up with so far is this:

HTML

```
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

CSS

```
#trapezoid {
    height: 0;
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom: 80px solid #05ed08;
    border-left: 45px solid transparent;
    border-right: 45px solid transparent;
    padding: 0 8px 0 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly2cmL4n/2/) that demonstrates a way to do it. In essence: give the image a shadow, overlay a transparent div on it that hides left, top and right border of the shadow. Because of these white borders this trick will not work if you use a complex background.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
.wrapper img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px black;
    margin: 0px 30px 50px 30px;
}
.wrapper .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 0px solid white;
    border-left: 30px solid white;
    border-right: 30px solid white;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg2RH.jpg" width="400" />
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle that plays with the positioning of the shadow. Not a true "trapezoid" but something a bit more in keeping with altering the "light source" that casts the shadow : http://jsfiddle.net/5ep343df/1/